# Dubai transit visa for Pakistani national

Tags: transit, dubai, pakistan

I live in Dubai. My brother has a Pakistani passport. He is on a study tour to the Netherlands. He has a flight to Lahore via Abu Dhabi. Is it possible for him to get a transit visa in Abu Dhabi airport for one week to stay in Dubai?

If yes, what is the procedure?

Comment: "one week" and visiting you are often not compatible with transit visa. Just ask a regular visa.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, if your brother is planning to stay for a week it's not a transit visa that he'll need, but an entry permit.

To get an entry permit he'll need a sponsor in the UAE. If you are a permanent resident then you can act in this capacity. Otherwise the UAE airlines and hotels can do so.

Once you're ready to apply, you do so through the GDRFA who have several offices throughout the region. You can find full detail of the visa requirements, airline visa services, application procedure and links to the GDRFA offices on the [UAE government web site](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae)

Answer (score 3):

"Transit" is when your only reason for entering the country is to pass through on your way to somewhere else, for example to change planes. It's not enough that you leave the country in a different direction to the one that you arrived (e.g., Netherlands–UAE–Pakistan): you must also leave quickly.

The rules vary between countries and I've not checked the UAE's requirements. However, transit usually only allows you to be in the country for 24–48 hours. If you want to stay for a week, you usually need a tourist or visitor visa.

Comment: The US is unusual in that transits may nominally last up to 29 days, but even still, an air traveler who wants to remain in a US city for a week to visit someone will not be able to do so with a transit visa because the length of the stay reveals a purpose other than transit.  In other words, the actual purpose of the stay may be relevant in addition to the duration.

Comment: @phoog Heh. So maybe someone who has no friends in Washington state, Oregon or California could cycle from Vancouver to Tijuana on a transit visa. :-)

Comment: Perhaps, though the choice to travel by bicycle might be seen as giving the trip a recreational purpose.  I presume the 29-day period dates from the time before air travel was common and when roads were bad, so someone traveling between Canada and Mexico or between East Asia and Western Europe might reasonably cross the US by train or even by horse-drawn coach.  With the current road network, it's hard to imagine a legitimate transit of the US taking more than a week.

Answer (score 0):

Transit means you can stay not more than 1 day. You will have to apply for 7 days Dubai visa. Get in touch with a local tour and travel company, they may assist you.